# How to convert a multi-stop css3 gradient into an image?

Tags: css, gradient

I have a multistop gradient created with colorzilla that I have successfully gotten to work as the background of my website.  It works perfectly for firefox, chrome, and IE9.  For IE7 and below, it only shows a white background, which is acceptible but not preferable, and to be frank, going back 2 generations, I am not worried about it.  However, IE8 only shows a gradient from the first color to the last color, no stops in the middle, which would normally get rid of the middle color, which was white in my case.  For the purposes of making it somewhat better, I changed it so the white would be the last color of that gradient, but it is by no means a perfect suggestion.

The solution, to me, appears to be converting my already created multistop gradient from the css code it is in into an image that I can repeat endlessly as necessary, as was traditionally done before the modern era of css gradients.  However, I have been unable to find any sort of tool or code that would allow me to do this for a given height and width.  Does anyone know of any tool, preferably free, that would satisfy these needs?  For the purpose of this question, the gradient code I am using is the following:

```
background: #72b4f9; /* Old browsers */

/* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */

background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);

background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #72b4f9 0%, #ffffff 25%, #ffffff 45%, #57c14f 96%, #397731 100%); /* FF3.6+ */

background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#72b4f9), color-stop(25%,#ffffff), color-stop(45%,#ffffff), color-stop(96%,#57c14f), color-stop(100%,#397731)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */

background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #72b4f9 0%,#ffffff 25%,#ffffff 45%,#57c14f 96%,#397731 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */

background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #72b4f9 0%,#ffffff 25%,#ffffff 45%,#57c14f 96%,#397731 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */

background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #72b4f9 0%,#ffffff 25%,#ffffff 45%,#57c14f 96%,#397731 100%); /* IE10+ */

background: linear-gradient(top, #72b4f9 0%,#ffffff 25%,#ffffff 45%,#57c14f 96%,#397731 100%); /* W3C */

filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#A2CEFB', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up finding a website that did essentially what I wanted at http://gradcolor.com/.  I was able to create multiple gradients at a specific size, and the website created the file for me to download and upload to the website.  Thank you everyone for your suggestions, as they led to me finding this.

Comment: does not work anymore

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try CSS3Pie http://css3pie.com  it is a quick/free solution for IE7/IE8

Or create a SVG image using the Gradient Background Maker
http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/graphics/svggradientbackgroundmaker/default.html

Then find a way to import to photoshop

Comment: I took a look at CSS3Pie, but it didn't do quite what I wanted.  SVG images won't work on IE8 and before.  I had already actually created one for IE9.

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop always works for me. Im sure you could use GIMP though. A gradient dialog in any image program generally has the same sliders and attributes thet the css generator you used would. You should be bale to create a file at the canvas size you want then essentially use the gradient tool's dialog to set the same settings. For more on that ask on SuperUser or on a forum for users of the app you go with.

Im not aware of an app that will convert the css to an image.